# How can I count number of lines of several files which is tar.gz without decompressing it and print out filename and lines count?

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

A Tar.Gzipped file exist in a bucket in google cloud storage , I need to count number of lines in each file and print out file name and lines count.

Comment: You going to have to uncompress it somehow.

Comment: First, you need to download the file and then decompress it. Only after those two steps can you process the contents.

Comment: Something like `curl https://cloud/address/...../ -o - | gunzip -c | wc` will be as fast as you can go, if you can't login to the a connected server where the file lives. You can use `printf "%s\t%s\n" "filename" $( curl .. as above)` and with a little fiddling you'll be able to get the output you want. Not certain about exact `curl` syntax, but `-o -` writes the stream to std-out, where it can be processed by `gunzip -c` which write the uncompress stream to the next pipe. which will produce the std `wc` output. Good luck.